# c programming: what is the difference of the type conversions?

Tags: c

Given the following C code, what is the difference between `a = f;` and `a = (int *) f;`?

```
float *f;
int *a;
...
a = f;
a = (int *) f;
```

Comment: One will not compile, and *neither* are defined behavior.

Comment: First is error, second compiles using typecasting

Comment: @WhozCraig just `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type` with MingW

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; There is no `typecasting` in standard rather `casting`. Typecasting is often used in film industries :) .

Comment: @WhozCraig Depends on compiler options.  Both compile (with a warning) using VS 2010.  I would expect the same from most compilers.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan http://ideone.com/vD7LME

Comment: @P0W Working!! not compilation error!!, undefined behaviour but...Thanks!

Comment: @Kejia You should not change question after getting answers because the answers might become invalid to your modifications. if you need anything more you can simply comment or else add Your edit at the bottom of question.

Answer (score 5):

```
float *f;
int *a;

a = f;
```

This assignment is erroneous (there is a C constraint violation), there is no implicit conversion between pointer types (except with `void *`). A compiler can refuse to compile a program with this assignment.

Comment: Let's consider `f = a` and `f = (float *)a`, and what's the difference?

Comment: @Kejia `f = a` violates a C constraint and `f = (float *)a` does not. Nevertheless the latter is dubious in the sense it may indicate you are doing something wrong in your program.

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
float *f;
int *a;
```

This:

```
a = f;
```

is a *constraint violation*. It requires a *diagnostic* from any conforming compiler. After issuing the required diagnostic, it may or may not reject the program. (IMHO it should do so.) A conforming compiler may choose to accept it with a mere warning (which qualifies as a diagnostic), but once it does so the behavior of the program is undefined. Compilers that do this most commonly generate an implicit conversion from `float*` to `int*`, giving the same behavior as if there were a cast (an explicit conversion), but the standard does not require that.

Non-conforming compilers, of course are free to do anything they like.

Conclusion: Don't write code like that. Even if your compiler lets you get away with it, another compiler might not. If you want to convert from one pointer type to another, use a cast. Aside from validity issues, the cast makes it much clearer to the reader that something funny is going on. If your compiler gave you a warning, heed it. If it didn't, find out how to increase the warning levels on your compiler.

This:

```
a = (int *) f;
```

takes the value of `f` (which is of type `float*`) and explicitly *converts* it to type `int*`, then assigns that `int*` value to `a`. (I'll assume that something between the declaration and the assignment has set `f` to some valid value.)

If `f` is a null pointer, the conversion is well defined, and yields a null pointer of type `int*`. The rules for converting a non-null object pointer to another pointer type are (quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.2.3p7):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.

This kind of conversion, assuming `int` and `float` are the same size and have similar alignment requirements, is likely intended to let you treat a `float` object as if it were an `int` object. This is called "type-punning". If `int` and `float` *aren't* the same size, or if they have different alignment requirements, this can easily blow up in your face, crashing your program (if you're lucky) or giving you garbage results (if you're not). (Yes, crashing the program is a *good* outcome; it lets you know there's a problem.)

If you really need to do that for some reason, it's better to define a `union` with `int` and `float` members, or to use `memcpy()` to copy the contents of a `float` object into an `int` object.

But it very rarely makes sense to do that kind of thing. If you want to examine the representation of a `float` object, it's better to treat it as an array of `unsigned char` something that the language standard explicitly permits.

Comment: Can constraint violation invokes UB?

Comment: @haccks: If a compiler rejects a program due to a constraint violation, then there is no behavior, defined or not. If it accepts it (after a mandatory warning), then yes, I'd argue that the behavior is undefined. There's a counterargument in this case: the standard does say that the expression is converted to the type of the object being initialized (the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, see N1570 6.7.9p11, 6.5.16.1p1). But personally I think it's a bit of a stretch to say that the semantics still apply after a constraint has been violated.

Comment: @haccks: See also the definition of "constraint", N1570 3.8: "restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is to be interpreted".

Comment: 6.5.16.1 says: `the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;`. What does it mean by the last line **...and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right**?

Comment: @haccks: Not relevant to this question, but for example you can't assign a `const int*` (pointer to const int) value to an `int*` object. If it were permitted, you could bypass `const`-ness without a cast. With gcc, you get warnings like "warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type".

Comment: Actually I came to this after reading the references you had provided. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

### 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
> the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
> pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of **compatible types**, and the type pointed
> to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right.

So, `a = f` is a constraint violation and invokes undefined behavior.

In second case you are making `f` (by casting it)to be **compatible** to `a`'s type. It is legal to do a casting in C (not sure about other languages).
But it should be noted that after casting `f` is still pointer to `float` and you have to cast it every time when you will assign it to `a`.

Comment: @DyP; That's interesting. If a compiler rejects a program due to a constraint violation, then there is no behavior, defined or not. If it accepts it (after a mandatory warning), then yes, I'd argue that the behavior is undefined. There's a counterargument in this case: the standard does say that the expression is converted to the type of the object being initialized (the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, see N1570 6.7.9p11, 6.5.16.1p1). But personally I think it's a bit of a stretch to say that the semantics still apply after a constraint has been violated.

Comment: @Dyp; Read comments on the this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19325025/2455888).

Comment: Yeah I just saw that a minute after posting the comment ;)

Comment: Then I saw [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/WNVXRSCqrGU). Although I'm not convinced that a *diagnostic message* is supposed to make behaviour of the whole program undefined, as it's mostly interpreted as a *warning* not an *error* by the compilers.

Answer (score 2):

`a = (int*) f;` makes explicit that you want to cast a `float*` pointer to an `int*` pointer. Without it, you'll receive an incompatible pointer types error.

Comment: There is no any *practical* difference except for a warning?

Comment: @Kejia; Yes there is!

Answer (score 2):

Your code will compile (at least in my linux and gcc). But you will get a warning.
If you use `a = f;` and then use `a` somewhere in your code, you will get erroneous data, because a float is stored in a different format in memory. Even if you do the casting first you probably will get erroneous results, but the compiler sees your casting and assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: Actually, I just want to know whether an explicit casting is always necessary. Let's consider `f = a` and `f = (float *)a`, and what's the difference?

Comment: @Kejia; Yes. In this case by casting you are promoting `a` to `float` type.

Comment: @haccks Don't you mean "to a `float *` type"?

Comment: I don't remember if the casting `f = (float*)a` will do any good. I know it won't generate the warning, but if I'm not mistaken, `a` will still be a pointer to int (C does not use dynamic types). So, you will  have to cast every time you want to use `a`, for example `float c = (*f) + (*(float*)a);` (this is a bad example, because C will use coercion in this case, but you get the idea).

Comment: @cenouro  Although often is, a pointer to `int` need not be the same size, alignment, (& other factors) as a pointer to `float`.  By explicitly stating `(float *)`, a compiler knows the coder is not errantly performing a cast.  The compiler may need to perform something other than a simple copy of the pointer.  Further, subsequent use may or may not require a cast of `a`.  It depends on the genesis and usage of `a`.  Your example provides a typical case where a cast is needed, but other select uses exist that would not require a cast.

Comment: @chux I know a `int` may not have the same size as a `float`, but a `int*` will 99.999999% be the same size as a `float*` because both variables store a memory address. Even `double*` will have the same size, since x86 implements the differences in the hardware, not in the compiler. About my example, it is bad because, if I'm not mistaken, gcc will use coercion (or implicit casting): `float c = 20.0 + 1` will be converted to `float c = 20.0 + 1.0`. A better example would be `int c = 1 + 2.0`. In this case, gcc will either produce and error or replace `2.0` with a bogus value.

Comment: One more thing: I'm assuming the pointers point to one element, not an array or an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = f; //assignment
// is a constraint violation

a = (int *) f; //cast + assignment
```

Explicitly  casting float pointer to int pointer.simply hides compiler warnings or errors. 
but very well might crash when running as the sizes of what the program expects when dereferencing the pointer differs from reality.

Comment: It should be `casting`.

Comment: `a = f;` is a constraint violation.

Comment: yes you are right.sorry did not added in my answer As OP needs the difference between these two.I will add now.